# Get First Column of CSV file javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, multiple-columns

Have tried PapaParse without success, how would one get the first column value of a CSV file?

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');


(async () => {
    try {

        fs.createReadStream('test.csv')
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', (row) => {
                console.log(row);
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                console.log('CSV file successfully processed');

            });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(error(err));
        await browser.close();
        console.log(error("Browser Closed"));
    }
})();
```

Comment: You need to create an accumulator (eg: an empty array) before creating the read stream. Then, in the on('data') callback, you would push the first item in the row into the accumulator. Finally, in the on('end') callback, you resolve the promise with the value in the accumulator.

Of course, you need to wrap your logic in a promise callback to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future, set a function then set as a const to your CSV list of URLs, the number [1] represents the column.

```
function readURLFile(path) {
    return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')
        .split('\n')
        .map((elt) => {
            const url = elt.split(',')[1].replace('\r', '');
            return `http://${url.toLowerCase()}`;
        });
}
```